# Chrome + ExtJS SVG Image Rendering Issue

Tags: google-chrome, extjs, svg, extjs4

I'm using an ExtJS (4.1.1) DrawComponent and have several stacked Sprites (image style). In Chrome (Version 34.0.1847.131), the topmost image elements do not render correctly.

Hard to explain exactly what is wrong though it seems that the images are being cropped/clipped in random and incorrect ways.

I haven't exhaustively tested in every known browser but can report that my latest versions of Safari, Firefox, and IE11 renders the SVG correctly.

While I'm doing this in ExtJS, I don't necessarily have any reason to believe it as an ExtJS specific problem but I can't rule it out for sure, either.

I put together a quick JSFiddle of the issue, here: http://jsfiddle.net/jdischler/D42de/6/

Just click on the Sprout icon and note that the popup icons are likely not rendered correctly in Chrome.

NOTE: The fiddle code is not the exact same as whats in the larger app but the fiddle showcases the problem in similar ways.

The basic concept here is a series of overlapped image sprites and it isn't working in Chrome. Chrome bug? Conceptual problem? Suggestions?

Here's the SVG that Ext generates from the fiddle script if that helps:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="288" height="266" id="ext-gen1037" style="width: 288px; height: 266px;">
    <defs></defs>
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#000" stroke="none" opacity="0" id="ext-gen1038"></rect>
    <rect id="ext-sprite-1019" zIndex="10" width="288" height="266" fill="#385" ry="0" rx="0" x="0" y="0" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></rect>
    <rect id="ext-sprite-1020" zIndex="20" width="180" height="180" r="15" x="10" y="10" fill="#864" stroke="#364" stroke-width="15" ry="15" rx="15" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></rect>
    <image id="ext-sprite-1021" xlink:href="http://fieldsoffuel.org/game/resources/field_overlay.png" zIndex="50" src="http://fieldsoffuel.org/game/resources/field_overlay.png" x="10" y="10" opacity="1" width="180" height="180" preserveAspectRatio="none" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></image>
    <image id="ext-sprite-1022" xlink:href="http://fieldsoffuel.org/game/resources/planting_icon.png" zIndex="100" src="http://fieldsoffuel.org/game/resources/planting_icon.png" x="20" y="160" opacity="0.75" width="50" height="50" preserveAspectRatio="none" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></image>
    <image id="ext-sprite-1026" xlink:href="http://209.85.48.18/7059/133/0/p1015675/shadow.png" class="" zIndex="200" src="http://209.85.48.18/7059/133/0/p1015675/shadow.png" x="-20" y="125" opacity="1" height="130" width="130" hidden="false" preserveAspectRatio="none" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></image>
    <image id="ext-sprite-1023" xlink:href="http://fieldsoffuel.org/game/resources/grass_icon.png" class="" zIndex="3000" src="http://fieldsoffuel.org/game/resources/grass_icon.png" x="-5" y="135" width="50" height="50" opacity="0.75" hidden="false" preserveAspectRatio="none" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></image>
    <image id="ext-sprite-1024" xlink:href="http://fieldsoffuel.org/game/resources/corn_icon.png" class="" zIndex="3000" src="http://fieldsoffuel.org/game/resources/corn_icon.png" x="45" y="135" width="50" height="50" opacity="0.75" hidden="false" preserveAspectRatio="none" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></image>
    <image id="ext-sprite-1025" xlink:href="http://fieldsoffuel.org/game/resources/cover_crop_icon.png" class="" zIndex="3000" src="http://fieldsoffuel.org/game/resources/cover_crop_icon.png" x="20" y="185" width="50" height="50" opacity="0.75" hidden="false" preserveAspectRatio="none" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">  </image>
</svg>
```

Comment: This might be http://crbug.com/363736, does it work correctly for you using Chrome 35? FWIW it works fine for me in Chrome 36 (dev).

Comment: Indeed it does work in v35beta. Unsure that I want to wait for the beta or not, blah. Any comments on whether this is conceptually a suitable way of achieving what is shown? If we don't want to wait for the beta, I'm wondering if this could be done without SVG. I'm not sure that is a good idea, though.